# Test if value exists in several lists

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, boolean-logic

I would like to check if a value exists in every list.

The following returns `True` as expected, but seems un-pythonic.

What is the correct/more elegant way to do this?

```
a = [1 ,2]
b = [1, 3]
c = [1, 4]
d = [2, 5]

False in [True if 1 in l else False for l in [a, b, c, d]  ]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#grammar-token-generator_expression):

```
all(1 in x for x in (a, b, c, d))
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [1 ,2]
>>> b = [1, 3]
>>> c = [1, 4]
>>> d = [2, 5]
>>> all(1 in x for x in (a, b, c, d))
False
>>> all(1 in x for x in (a, b, c))
True
>>>
```

In addition to being more readable, this solution is more efficient since it uses lazy-evaluation.  It will only check as many items as is necessary to determine the result.

Also, there is never a good reason to do:

```
True if 1 in l else False
```

or something similar since `in` already returns a boolean result.  All you need is:

```
1 in l
```

For the negated version, use:

```
1 not in l
```