# check if a value is in several lists

Tags: python

The task: check if 'value' is in list_1 AND list_2

Approach below - is the result of 2 minutes intuitive playing

```
list_1 = ['3', '5']
list_2 = ['5', '7', '4']
r = '5' in (list_1 and list_2) # 'and' gets an intersection
print(r) #True
```

And it works in a way I expect. I've already seen solution like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715213/test-if-value-exists-in-several-lists) - it works, but there is a little room of my misunderstanding, that's why I ask

(1) Can't find docs, describing how 'and' operator (should)works,
for list, dicts, tuples etc.

(2) Why the following code returns *'False'*

```
list_1 = ['3', '5']
list_2 = ['5', '7', '4']
r = '5' in (list_1, list_2) # Tuple?
print(r) #False
```

(3) Why it returns *['5', '7', '4']*

```
list_1 = ['3', '5']
list_2 = ['5', '7', '4']
r = '5' in list_1 and list_2
print(r) # ['5', '7', '4']
```

(4) Why it returns *(True, ['5', '7', '4'])*

```
list_1 = ['3', '5']
list_2 = ['5', '7', '4']
r = '5' in list_1, list_2
print(r) # (True, ['5', '7', '4'])
```

I believe there is some doc at python docs web site, which enlightens questions above. It is possible to spend some time learning python 3 source code to see implementation details, but I am wondering of some language standart(like ECMAScript) which was used when Python 3 implementing

Comment: You can use the intersection method of Python's set type for this task. As for what Python's `and` & `or` operators do, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36551857/4014959).

Comment: @PM 2Ring, thank you for your comment - it is helpful + using a set solves that task too: '5' in set(p1.extend(p2))

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition about the first snippet is False. `and` returns the second of its operators if both are truthy, so here it returns the second list; so your statement is actually equivalent to `'5' in list_2`, which happens to be True.

The second is false because the tuple is actually now `(['3', '5'], ['5', '7', '4'])` - ie a tuple of two elements, both of which are lists. `in` will check if any members of the tuple are the string '5', but neither of them are.

The other two answers are just to do with operator precedence; the third is equivalent to `('5' in list_1) and list_2` which returns list_2 as explained above; and the third is equivalent to `(('5' in list_1), list_2)`.

Comment: `True and [5,7,4]` returns `[5,7,4]` so that's the last not the first (but it still works since 5 is in both lists)

Comment: Sorry, I mis-wrote; updated.

Comment: Maybe meta, but: should answers using the jargon "truthy" clarify that it means `bool(thing)` evaluates to `True`? Or is it a term that has wider use than Python and we'd expect a beginner to know?

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you for your explanation - it is helpful and quick answered